# Требуется принимать параметр check RadioButton`a из второй win формы в класс

Tags: c#, winforms

Собственно говоря в заголовке вопроса все расписано 
Класс:

```
    public class Game
{
    private Ball ball = new Ball();
    private Planet planet = new Planet();
    public static FormSett FS = new FormSett();
    public void HandleKey(Keys keys)
    {
        if (FS.rbtnWS.Checked) //radiobutton - 1 
        {
            if (keys == Keys.W)
            {
                this.ball.Vy = -10;
            }
            else if (keys == Keys.S)
            {
                this.ball.Vy = 10;
            }
        }
        if (FS.rbtnUpDown.Checked) //radiobutton - 2
        {
            if (keys == Keys.Up)
            {
                this.ball.Vy = -10;
            }
            else if (keys == Keys.Down)
            {
                this.ball.Vy = 10;
            }
        }
    }
```

Вторая форма:

```
public partial class FormSett : Form
{
    static Form1 F1 = new Form1();
    private Game game = new Game();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rbtnWS.Checked = true;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rbtnUpDown.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

Класс не видит значение Radiobutton`a

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ну естественно не видит! Вы же обращаетесь не к той форме! Обратитесь через объект формы, далее к ее полям.

Comment: @Yami
Можно попросить о более точную формулировку?

Answer (score 1):

Можно вспомнить о событиях и поработать с ними.

Форма с радиокнопками

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    //объявляем события для каждой радиокн.
    public event EventHandler DiamondsClickEvent;
    public event EventHandler SpadesClickEvent;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //обработчик события Click на радиокнопке бубнов
    private void radioButtonDiamonds_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //вызываем наше ранее объявленное событие для бубнов
        DiamondsClickEvent?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }

    private void radioButtonSpades_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //вызываем наше ранее объявленное событие для пик
        SpadesClickEvent?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Основная форма

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonOpenForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //создаем форму
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        //подписываемся на наши события в форме 2
        form2.DiamondsClickEvent += Form2_DiamondsClickEvent;
        form2.SpadesClickEvent += Form2_SpadesClickEvent;
        //отображаем форму
        form2.Owner = this;
        form2.Show();
    }

    //обработчик события пик
    private void Form2_SpadesClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton radioButton = sender as RadioButton;
        if (radioButton == null) return;

        string message = radioButton.Checked ? "Пики вкл." : "Пики выкл.";

        listBoxOutput.Items.Add(message);
    }

    //обработчик события бубен
    private void Form2_DiamondsClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton radioButton = sender as RadioButton;
        if (radioButton == null) return;

        string message = radioButton.Checked ? "Бубны вкл." : "Бубны выкл.";

        listBoxOutput.Items.Add(message);
    }
}
```

Выглядит это так

[image: демонстрация работы примера]